# Remove the particular item from the array - react native

Tags: react-native, es6-class

How can I remove the particular item from the array loop if the condition matches?

```
array.map(item => {
   item.id === companyId ? 
      //how to remove this item from the array??
} : null)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run filter on the array first: `array.filter( item => item.id !== companyId ).map( ... )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native JS `.filter` method

```
const newArray = array.filter(item => item.id !== companyId)
```

This will return a new array without the matching item.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```js
var data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

const result = data.filter(val => val.id != 2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can also use `_.remove` from lodash

`const newArray = _.remove(array, item => item.id === companyId)`